# LXDE, Ubuntu 14.04 - use i3 as WM instead

Tags: ubuntu, lxde, i3

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 with LXDE using crouton on my chromebook and it's working fine, I would like to try using i3 with it instead though (which is what I usually have on my main system).

I'm not sure how to go about this - on my other system it was just a case of choosing i3 then selecting it (instead of Unity) at the login screen, which I don't have on this system.

So how do i go about this? I've found an option that says `openbox` under `desktop session settings > advanced options`, but I'm not sure that just changing this to `i3` would be a good option.

What steps I should take in order to setup i3 with lubuntu as I'm using it?

I installed `i3` using the default apt package manager, if I enter `which i3` I get `/usr/bin/i3` returned.

The contents of `/usr/share/xsessions` are 4 files :

- `LXDE.desktop`
- `i3-with-shmlog.desktop`
- `i3.desktop`
- `openbox.desktop`

> "*And in case you have an i3 .desktop file there, make sure its display on your login screen is allowed*"

In response to [this reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231895/lxde-ubuntu-14-04-use-i3-as-wm-instead#comment396030_231895) leading to [this ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/327195/381385),
I'm not sure that it's relevant as I'm not logging in with the Ubuntu log in screen, on my main system I do and it's very easy to select `i3` from there, but this system is a **Chromebook** and I'm accessing Ubuntu using `crouton`, so I don't have the same log in process here (I don't have a log in screen...).

Comment: How did you install `i3`? What do you have in `/usr/share/xsessions`?

Comment: And in case you have an `i3` .desktop file there, make sure its display on your login screen is allowed: http://askubuntu.com/a/327195

Comment: Also, http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=26723